# How can I add minutes and seconds to a datetime in lua?

Tags: time, lua, rainmeter

I have a lua function to attempt to convert the time duration of the currently playing song e.g. hh:mm:ss to seconds.

```
function toSeconds (inputstr)
    local mytable = string.gmatch(inputstr, "([^"..":".."]+)");

    local conversion = { 60, 60, 24}
    local seconds = 0;
    --iterate backwards
    local count = 0;

    for i=1, v in mytable do
        count = i+1
    end

    for i=1, v in mytable do
        mytable[count-i]
        seconds = seconds + v*conversion[i]
    end
    return seconds
end
```

in order to add it to `os.time` to get the estimated end time of a song.

but the hours may be missing, or the minutes may be missing on a short track.

When running against https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo All I get is `input:10: 'do' expected near 'in'`

for the test script

```
function toSeconds (inputstr)
    local mytable = string.gmatch(inputstr, "([^"..":".."]+)");

    local conversion = { 60, 60, 24}
    local seconds = 0;
    --iterate backwards
    local count = 0;

    for i=1, v in mytable do
        count = i+1
    end

    for i=1, v in mytable do
        mytable[count-i]
        seconds = seconds + v*conversion[i]
    end
    return seconds
end

print(toSeconds("1:1:1")
```

Comment: `for i=1, v in mytable do` this is incorrect. Read [about](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html) [loops](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up the two possible ways of writing a `for` loop:

**a**)

```lua
for i=1,10 do
   print(i, "This loop is for counting up (or down) a number")
end
```

**b**)

```lua
for key, value in ipairs({"hello", "world"}) do
   print(key, value, "This loop is for using an iterator function")
end
```

The first one, as you can see, simply counts up a number, `i` in this case. The second one is very generic and can be used to iterate over almost anything (for example using `io.lines`), but is most often used with `pairs` and `ipairs` to iterate over tables.

You also don't write `for ... in tab`, where `tab` is a table; you have to use `ipairs` for that, which then returns an iterator for the table (which is a function)

---

You're also using `string.gmatch` incorrectly; it doesn't return a table, but an iterator function over the matches of the pattern in the string, so you can use it like this:

```lua
local matches = {}
for word in some_string:gmatch("[^ ]") do
   table.insert(matches, word)
end
```

which gives you an actual table containing the matches, but if you're only going to iterate over that table, you might as well use the `gmatch` loop directly.

---

```lua
for i=1, v in mytable do
   count = i+1
end
```

I think you're just trying to count the elements in the table here? You can easily get the length of a table with the `#` operator, so `#mytable`

---

If you have a string like `hh:mm:ss`, but the hours and the minutes can be missing, the easiest thing might be to just fill them with 0. A somewhat hacky but short way to achieve this is to just append `"00:00:"` to your string, and look for the last 3 numbers in it:

```
local hours, minutes, seconds = ("00:00:"..inputstr):match("(%d%d):(%d%d):(%d%d)$")
```

If nothing is missing, you'll end up with something like `00:00:hh:mm:ss`, which you only take the last 3 values of to end up with the correct time.

Comment: The trouble with using gmatch directly, is I need to reverse the order, because of optional elements. I've had a lot of trouble iterating over it backwards, which makes sense if it's not a table I guess. This is like my 5th attempt before getting frustrated. I was almost hoping it was an xy problem, that had an easier fix.

Comment: My research regarding ` You can easily get the length of a table with the # operator, so #mytable` said that # is technically undefined for tables, this may have been fixed in a newer version of lua, but I'm not sure what version is packaged with rainmeter.

Comment: `#` is never undefined. For sequences, it returns the length, the only "weird" thing happens when your table has gaps, like `{1, 2, nil, 4}`, in which case `#` will return either `2` or `4`, depending on certain implementation details; but that's still *defined* behavior, and it doesn't happen as often as one might expect in the real world.

Comment: `depending on certain implementation details` is kinda the definition of undefined behavior as far as I was concerned, when looking at lua as a whole? I'll have another go when it's in front of me next.

Comment: it *is* defined though. Undefined behavior could mean your computer explodes; `#` has a pretty clear definition, it's just not deterministic in all situations, but neither is `math.random` and we're not calling that undefined either. Neither will return a string, or format your hard disk, or launch a nuke at you. Undefined behavior, as it's commonly understood in programming, *might* do any of those things.